# WSDL Client Generation not complete?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, tibco, xfire

Just tried to generate java client generation from a WSDL file ( using XFire using XMLBeans binding )

I am able to generate the client + Fault Message ( no error ) , however input message and output message was not generated, it's also not generating the operation in the client. Is there anything wrong with my WSDL file, or is there anything I miss ?

Update :

1. I updated my test XFire project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/chiq6oi5uk91i66/X-OQtVnL91).
2. I begin to suspect that the problem can be isoldated to the WSDL (because I can generate other WSDL successfully). I found these warnings, which I feel related :

   > WS-I: (BP2402) The wsdl:binding element does not use a
   >   soapbind:binding element as defined in section "3 SOAP Binding." of
   >   the WSDL 1.1 specification.
   >
   > WS-I: (BP2032) Defective soapbind:fault element: the "name" attribute value does not match the value of the "name" attribute on
   >   the parent element wsdl:fault.
   >
   > WS-I: (AP2901) A description uses neither the WSDL MIME Binding as described in WSDL 1.1 Section 5 nor WSDL SOAP binding as described in
   >   WSDL 1.1 Section 3 on each of the wsdl:input or wsdl:output elements
   >   of a wsdl:binding.
3. Just found that soap12 might caused the issue. If I changed the xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" to xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" and removing soapActionRequired in soap:operation it can generated the client successfully. But the webservice is currently only in soap1.2 only. So changing the wsdl to use soap1.1 is not the case here.

Here is my WSDL file :

```
<!--Created by TIBCO WSDL-->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/WSDL/service/CBS-CustAccountInfo-I" xmlns:soap1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:jndi="http://www.tibco.com/namespaces/ws/2004/soap/apis/jndi" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:jms="http://www.tibco.com/namespaces/ws/2004/soap/binding/JMS" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Untitled" targetNamespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/WSDL/service/CBS-CustAccountInfo-I">

<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
        <xs:include schemaLocation="../Schemas/XML/CBS-CustAccountInfo-I-ServiceEnvelope.xsd"/>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:service name="CBS-CustAccountInfo-I">
    <wsdl:port name="CBS-CustAccountInfo-I_HTTP" binding="tns:CBS-CustAccountInfo-I_HTTPBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://localhost:15038/Services/CBS-CustAccountInfo-I/Processes/MainRequestResponse_HTTP"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
<wsdl:portType name="PortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="CBS-CustAccountInfo-I">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:InputMessage"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:OutputMessage"/>
        <wsdl:fault name="fault1" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="CBS-CustAccountInfo-I_HTTPBinding" type="tns:PortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="CBS-CustAccountInfo-I">
        <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="/Services/CBS-CustAccountInfo-I/Processes/MainRequestResponse_HTTP" soapActionRequired="true"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" parts="InputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" parts="OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="fault1">
            <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault1"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:message name="InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="InputMessage" element="ns:ServiceEnvelope"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="OutputMessage" element="ns:ServiceEnvelope"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="FaultMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="FaultMessage" element="ns:ServiceEnvelope"/>
</wsdl:message>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And here is my ant task to generate :

```
<!-- Generating XML Beans -->   
<target name="gen-xmlbeans">
<java classname="org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler"
          classpathref="build.classpath"
          fork="true">
      <arg value="-out"/>
      <arg value="${basedir}/lib/ocbc.jar"/>
      <arg value="${schema.path}"/>
</java>
</target>

<!-- Generating Client -->
<target name="ws-generate">
        <taskdef name="wsgen" classname="org.codehaus.xfire.gen.WsGenTask">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
            </classpath>    
        </taskdef>    
        <wsgen outputDirectory="${basedir}/src/" wsdl="${wsdl.path}" package="test.client" overwrite="true" binding="xmlbeans"/>                
</target>
```

Generated Client :

```
public class CBS_CustAccountInfo_IClient {

private static XFireProxyFactory proxyFactory = new XFireProxyFactory();
private HashMap endpoints = new HashMap();

public CBS_CustAccountInfo_IClient() {
}

public Object getEndpoint(Endpoint endpoint) {
    try {
        return proxyFactory.create((endpoint).getBinding(), (endpoint).getUrl());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new XFireRuntimeException("Invalid URL", e);
    }
}

public Object getEndpoint(QName name) {
    Endpoint endpoint = ((Endpoint) endpoints.get((name)));
    if ((endpoint) == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No such endpoint!");
    }
    return getEndpoint((endpoint));
}

public Collection getEndpoints() {
    return endpoints.values();
}

}
```

Comment: XFire is old, nonstandard, and unsupported. You might be happier with Apache CXF, its successor.

Comment: I know, too bad I have to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rudy If you have to use XFire, you might consider to try other binding such as JAXB binding and see if you're able to get the code generated properly.

Comment: We tried using the JAXB and we are having another issue with the duplicate element ( since the schemas referenced each other ).

Comment: @Rudy Are you saying there are multiple schemas and some of them referencing each other? In that case, would you possibly to merge those schemas that are referencing each other. That could be the same issue that causing XMLBeans unable to generate properly.

Comment: XMLBeans generation was successful ( and can be used in SOAP 1.1 )